# How to pop up code completion hint and word expand together in Webstorm?

Tags: webstorm

I want to show pop up code completion hint and word expand (which is equal to Ctrl + N in Vim). Now I type Ctrl+E to popup expand word and I type Ctrl + Shift to popup code completion hint...

Do you have any idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the lesser-known but potentially powerful features of the keymap is that you can map multiple actions to the same shortcut. You could try doing this for the two things you want to have happen at once.

In **Settings → Keymap**, you can change what action is triggered by what shortcut.

You can find the actions you're looking for either by name (if you know what they're called in WebStorm), or by their shortcut (by clicking on the *Find actions by shortcut* button next to the action name search box).

Once you've decided which keyboard shortcut you want to trigger both actions, you can assign it to both actions.  You may get a popup about possible conflicts with other actions, with an option to either **Remove** the other shortcuts or **Leave** them be.

It may be obvious at this point, but you want to **Leave** the other shortcut in place so that both actions will be triggered.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, check the related requests:

- [IDEABKL-3262](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-3262) Word Completion
- [IDEABKL-6021](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6021) introduce new completion type similar to expand word

The first request is most likely your use case:

> provide reasonable variants to complete when any completion based on context language analysis fail or absent